# Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-5.6

I'm using Laravel package [Tymon JWT](http://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/laravel-installation/) and it was working fine so far. But I tried to install Laravel intervention package and ran Composer update command after which it stopped working and started giving errors as I mentioned.

I've tried all the answers like removing it and reinstalling it back, composer update, install, but still same error and whole project is stopped now.

I've added this in provider's array:

```
Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class,
```

Composer:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.0",
    "irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard": "^1.0",
    "jadjoubran/laravel-angular": "^0.4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "^0.5.12"
},
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: have you tried to move scripts from pre-install-cmd to post-install-cmd in the composer instructions?

Comment: @AlexSlipknot what'll it do? and how to add in composer?

Comment: pre-install-cmd: occurs before the install command is executed with a lock file present
pre-update-cmd: occurs before the update command is executed, or before the install command is executed without a lock file present.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md

Comment: @AlexSlipknot no it didn't worked. Still same error. It was working fine till today. I just installed Laravel intervention package and run composer update command after that it stopped everything.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the line that you added to the array, then run composer install and then add the code to the array again.

Comment: Did you try to run composer dump-autoload?

Comment: No, can you please tell me the sequence in which I've to run commands and when to add it in providers array? Currently I've removed this package.

Comment: Normally you should first install a package, and after, add it to the service providers array. I mean, adding it to the array is the last thing.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

`Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class,`

in providers array, then in terminal run the following command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider"
```